# site columns with a different value and display text

Tags: 2010, site-column, choice-field

is it possible to create a choice site column that has a display value that actual differs from the real value.  as an example i want a site column that displays a list of colours but i want the actual values to be in hex.

```
column display value | Actual column value
White                  #ffffff
Black                  #1a1a18
Dark Grey              #7b7865
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box. You can possibly do something with Jquery/Javascript that will change the values of the choices on a NewForm.aspx page. I would say that the values can be the hex, and upon a new form, then javascript would be the answer to change those hex values into something readable by end-users. This article might point you to the right direction: [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/using-javascript-to-manipulate-a-list-form-field)

Another answer would be to create your own webpart that would read the hex values and translate them into a readable text to end-users..